# Android cellular connection IP address

Tags: android, cellular-network

How can I get my current IP address when I'm connected to cellular? 
I know I can use NetworkInterface as explained here:

[Getting IP address of Android when connected to Cellular Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182782/getting-ip-address-of-android-when-connected-to-cellular-network)

but I want to avoid doing network operations and looking for something similar to wifi with `WifiManager.DhcpInfo` (the latest ip address cached by the os)

Comment: What do you consider to be a "network operation" in the links answer? It just enumerates the interfaces and check if it is the loopback device and if it has an IPv4 IP address.

Comment: Because it throws SocketException